# How to detect the more close period using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

If I have two `datetime` variables like this :

```
ST : 2016-02-07 08:00:00.000
END: 2016-02-07 16:00:00.000
```

Now if I have a third `datetime` variable like this :

```
INSERTED : 2016-02-07 17:00:00.000
```

Is there some function to detect which period more close to the `INSERTED`

I mean in my example it will be `END:2016-02-07 16:00:00.000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mixture of a case statement and datediff for this.

```
...
CASE 
    WHEN datediff(ms, st, inserted) < datediff(ms, inserted, end) THEN 'ST'
    WHEN datediff(ms, st, inserted) = datediff(ms, inserted, end) THEN 'Equal'
    ELSE THEN 'END'
END As Nearest
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any in-built function to do that - you may have to roll out your own. Within it you could take midpoint (i.e. `(ST + END)/2`) and compare that with `INSERTED` but that would require converting the dates to floats first.

There is a simplified way to do it without conversion, though, and I think its neat:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN [ST] + [END] - [INSERTED] > [INSERTED] THEN [ST]
        ELSE [END]
    END
    ...
```

That will work regardless of where `INSERTED` is in relation to start and end (but it does assume that start and end are in the correct order).